# Do I have to delete google analytics & FB pixel code if I wanna implement google tag manager?

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, google-tag-manager

Do I have to delete google analytics & FB pixel code if I wanna implement google tag manager?

Do you have any experience with that? I will be gladder if I can let it in code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can run analytics regardless of what else you run with it. The javascript for GA should be compatible. But I'm not very familiar with tag manager. We'll see what the tag manager users have to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put your GA code and Facebook code in via tag manager, then yes, delete the old code, or you'll double count. But you don't have to - you can leave old tags on and just put new ones in tag manager if that's what you want.

Though you have a lot more flexibility and functionality by putting those tags in tag manager